# C# Printing results into a table

Tags: c#, visual-studio, search, store

I am making an online store program extremely basic program in visual studios c#. I have a working search and I am trying to not only print the results to a table but also have each result being clickable to redirect to the items page for more detailed information.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 namespace BookStoreOnline
 {
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    private static Database dBase;
    private static string test;
    private static string testInfo;
    private static List<Book> resultList;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (SearchBox.Text != "")
        {
            dBase = new Database();
            resultList = new List<Book>();


            test = SearchCriteria.SelectedItem.Text;


            testInfo = SearchBox.Text;

            switch (test)
            {
                case "ISBN":
                    resultList = dBase.SearchISBN(testInfo);
                    break;
                case "Title":
                    resultList = dBase.SearchTitle(testInfo);
                    break;
                case "Author":
                    resultList = dBase.SearchAuthor(testInfo);
                    break;
                case "Semester":
                    resultList = dBase.SearchSemester(testInfo);
                    break;
                case "Course":
                    resultList = dBase.SearchCourse(testInfo);
                    break;
                case "Section":
                    resultList = dBase.SearchSection(testInfo);
                    break;
                case "Professor":
                    resultList = dBase.SearchProfessor(testInfo);
                    break;
                case "CRN":
                    resultList = dBase.SearchCRN(testInfo);
                    break;
            }

            if (resultList.Count == 0)
            {

                NoResults.Text = "No results were found.";
            }
            else
            {
                Results.Text = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < resultList.Count; i++)
                {
                    int j = i + 1;




                }
            }
        }
    }


    }
}
```

I had it printing out the results like this, but i could not have each of the individual items linked to their more info pages in any manner.

```
         //Results.Text += "<pre>" + j + ". Title: " + resultList[i].Title + "<br>" + "Author: " + resultList[i].Author + "<br><br>" +     </pre>";
```

Comment: Building the hyperlink (using the `<a href...>` element) depends on what parameter your item detail page accepts.

Comment: This is purely internal (I believe that's the right word), so it won't actually be hyperlinking. Instead it will be using Response.Redirect("BookInfo.aspx") and keeping track of which book was selected in the session for displaying information.

Comment: Hyperlinking works just as well for internal things and it really is *the* way to do  this sort of thing in a web application.

Answer (score -1):

You could try use DataGridView with a button per row and CommandArgument. And redirect to your product detail page.